# Write a static method named repeats_exist(numbers) that takes an array of integers as a parameter

Tags: java, arrays

> Write a static method named repeats_exist(numbers) that takes an array of integers as a parameter and returns true if there are any repeated values in the array, and false if all of the values in the array are unique. Note: you can assume that the array is not empty and the method returns a boolean value.

```
For example:

Test                                                             Result
System.out.println(repeats_exist(new int[]{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}));     false
System.out.println(repeats_exist(new int[]{2, 3, 4, 3, 6}));     true
```

Here is my attempt, but still have an error. Please help me to fix the problem.

```
static boolean repeats_exist(int a[],int n)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]==a[j])
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: hint: first solve it with paper and pen and then with java.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error (if so - which)? The wrong result?

Comment: Compare the signature of `repeat_exists` in the examples with your actual implementation.  How many parameters?  See the difference?

Comment: It is a syntax error. Please check the question.

Comment: *"It is a syntax error. Please check the question"* - I checked.  The question does not say that!   When you ask for help with debugging some code it is important that you **tell** us what the problem is.   Sure.  Eventually someone might manage to guess what your errors are ... eventually ... but guessing games are **inefficient**.

Answer (score 0):

Change method like this way

```
static boolean repeats_exist(int a[])
    {
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<a.length;j++)
            {
                if(a[i]==a[j])
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and the error will disappear

There is only one parameter value in the method offered as Example.

```
System.out.println(repeats_exist(new int[]{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}));
```

However, the declared method requires two parameters.
Maybe this is the reason for the error.

**We need to match the number of parameters for the method declaration and call.**
[image]

Or, when you call a method, you can adjust the number of parameters to get a normal result.

But because you have to put in the value of n directly [it's going to be the length of array a in this code], it's very annoying and it can cause other errors.

```
public class StackOver
{

    static boolean repeats_exist(int a[], int n)
    {
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i< n;i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j< n;j++)
            {
                if(a[i]==a[j])
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(repeats_exist(new int[]{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 5));
        System.out.println(repeats_exist(new int[]{2, 3, 4, 3, 6}, 5)); 
    }
 }
```

If you don't enter the '`n`' value correctly, it might not be properly scanned, resulting in incorrect results, or occurring an error (`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`) so I recommend the first method which using the length of the array passed to the parameter.